# Script online flash player

Tags: javascript, flash

I want to play/stop [Pandora](http://www.pandora.com/)'s web radio tuner, which is flash-based, via Javascript. How do I programmatically interact with it's online flash player?

Answer (score 0):

Someone correct me if im wrong, but you can not do this unless you put a function within the actionscript using ExternalInterface that will accept calls from the javascript and play/stop for example. Not sure what Pandora is, but if you don't have the source code (actionscript and fla) then i believe it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

This is against their terms of service.

> make the Pandora Services available over a network (other than
>   Pandora's network) or through an interface other than those provided
>   by Pandora or attempt to interfere with service to any user, host or
>   network;

I would suggest you contact them for API access.

Look under [Restrictions](http://www.pandora.com/legal/)

Comment: I want to drive their interface, not use another interface in lieu of it, so I don't think it applies.

Comment: It sure does apply Quote, "make the Pandora Services available over a network (other than Pandora's network) or through an interface other than those provided by Pandora "

Comment: That's the one I'm saying I don't think applies. I'm not replacing their interface, I'm just interacting with their existing interface. Binding a keyboard shortcut via Javascript to push the button on their player doesn't seem like an "other interface" to me.

Comment: Assuming you will be hosting this on your domain then it is not on a pandora network and as such TOS violation. I am not a lawyer and I am not giving legal advise here but I would strongly suggest you contact them first.

Comment: Okay, now I see the confusion. I want to add shortcut keys to Pandora, so that when I'm playing music on my machine, via their website, using their interface, I can hit Cmd-P to pause, instead of moving my mouse oner to the pause button. I'm not hosting anything.

Comment: It sounds like you want to make yourself a plugin of some type